# Why do I have an error "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a pagination and API call, the function gets all the items and divides it by the page number, so it displays 10 items on one page.

It looks like the following:

```
const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);  //state for pages
 const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);    //state for a limit of pages
 const [page, setPage] = useState(1);       //state for particular page
 let pagesArray = getPagesArray(totalPages);  //creates an array with all pages
export const getPagesArray = (totalPages) =>{  /getPagesArray function
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++){
        result.push(i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}

const [fetchPosts, isPostLoading, postError] = useFetching(async () =>{  
    const posts = await PostService.getAll(limit, page);  
    setPosts(posts.data);        //sets posts array to API data
    const totalCount = posts.headers['x-total-count'];    //gets posts count from an API
    setTotalPages(getPageCount(totalCount, limit));
  })

export default class PostService {    //PostService class
    static async getAll(limit = 10, page = 1){
            const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                params:{
                    _limit: limit,
                    _page: page
                }
            });
            return response;
    }
};

  useEffect(() => {  //useEffect for calling an API and changing pages
    fetchPosts();
  }, [page]);
```

So I did all this following a tutorial, and there it worked just fine, but I have next errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I tried to delete the next line:

```
setTotalPages(getPageCount(totalCount, limit));
```

And these errors disappeared, so it might be that, but I can't figure what's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an infinite loop in `useEffect`. `fetchPosts`  gets called when `page` changes, but that changes the `page` again, causing `fetchPosts` to be called again, ad infinitum.

Comment: I see, but the thing is, these errors occur even before I do something on the page. Like my page loads and there's nothing in the browser, and only these errors in the console

Comment: There's a couple other strange things going on, for example you are calling `let pagesArray = getPagesArray(totalPages)` on line 4, but at that time the state is still empty. When the state changes, you don't create that custom array again so it will remain empty.  Also, I don't see the function `getPageCount` anywhere? I would advise simplifying your code to the point where it works, and then add things back.